# Is the inline-then-optimize approach really Whole-Program Optimization?

Tags: java, optimization

I am working on a high-performance and pirated Minecraft version. I tried my best to totally outgun vanilla and legitimate Minecraft at the performance by using Advanced-Technology Whole-Program Optimization. I used an inline-then-optimize approach since it suits Minecraft the best (more aggressive Whole-Program Optimization techniques would break the game since the game is too complex to be statically analyzed ahead-of-time.). I also had a theory that Whole-Program Optimization is an enabling transformation that makes JIT Optimizations more powerful. Is the inline-then-optimize approach really Whole-Program Optimization? Are there other safe and better Whole-Program optimization techniques?

[[image: Libminecraft's advanced-technology whole-program optimization]]

Comment: According to a YouTube video I just watched, yes it is.  (I was wondering what you meant by *"Advanced-Technology Whole-Program Optimization"*.)  But wait ... it looks you uploaded that video yourself.  So if you already know the answer (as per your video), why are you asking this question?  (And where are the benchmarks, etc to support the claims in your YouTube video?)

Comment: Why are you doing this on a pirated version of a commercial property? You should either create your own game, or work for a company that has done this.

Comment: If you want my opinion, inlining at the bytecode level might improve startup times a bit ... but I doubt that they help once the code has been JIT compiled.  After all,  the JIT compiler does the exact same thing.  And for something like Minecraft, fast startup should not be that important.

Comment: And my answer to the question in the title is ... probably no.  Inlining and peephole optimizations are both local in effect.  But does it really matter how you label it?

Comment: My problem: some versions of libminecraft are AOT-Compiled since I used to have a belief that JIT Optimization is no use if libminecraft used its advanced-technology Whole-Program Optimization.